# Display post detail when clicking on a link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress theme implementation. On the home page I am displaying a post of a category. Whenever I click on any post I want to be directed to its detail page. How can I do this? And what is the single.php file and what code should I use in this file?

Comment: I can only advise you to improve your English skills or at least respect some of the simplest rules, like writing the "I" in uppercase. Also, asking for code is not welcome on SO. Usually people try to direct people into the right direction or at least give Code tips / snippets, some may even answer with the code you need, but still asking for code is rude.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new template file whose name will be
  `single-{the_post_type_name_you_are_showing}.php`.
- In this template you can have a global variable `$post` (*it's available by default*). So you can have titles (**like**: `$post->ID`), contents (**like**: `the_content()`), etc.
- Each post has a permalink. Use that as a link to details page.
- So After creating the template - and your posts linked -- you can see
  the post details.

Answer (score 0):

**First: "What is single.php"**

The single.php file is responsible for the rendering of a single post. You should definitely work with the WP Dev area: [developer.wordpress.com](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)
There you have to learn at first about the wordpress template hierarchy. You will also find out, that

> The single post template file is used to render a single post.

**Second: Link to detail page**

To get the "more detail" link you simply have to use

```
<?php get_post_permalink(); ?>
```

This will return the link to the post, while you are looping through your posts. [more here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_permalink)